# What is the simplest way to run Javascript code on Ubuntu?

Tags: programming, javascript

I tried to use browsers' console, but it interprets `print` as command to print a document, not as output on the console.
I heard about some JavaScript Shell, but didn't quiet get how to install and use it.
I need to run just trivial console Javascript programs.

Comment: In JS, `console.log` is for output, not `print`.

Comment: I also found projects like https://github.com/saghul/txiki.js based on QuickJS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to run JavaScript on your desktop is probably thorugh [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/). Install it with:

```
apt install nodejs
```

Then if you create a file named `hello.js` like this...

```javascript
console.log("Hello!");
```

...you can execute it like this:

```
$ node hello.js
Hello!
```

NodeJS comes with several modules for various tasks, including interacting with your desktop and creating graphical applications. Use `apt search ^node-` to list those packaged for Ubuntu, or check out [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) for many other third-party packages.